# Feedback Mechanism for FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-push-notification

I am using FCM for sending push notifications to individual devices.

I want to get acknowledgement for the notification receival at the device end.

Is there any way to receive the acknowledgement for the same?

Comment: You should show the code you are using to set up the notifications

Comment: const admin = require(firebase-admin)
admin.initializeApp({
credentials : admin.credential.cert(×××)
databaseURL: 'https://×××.firebaseio.com/'
)}

var tokens = [list of tokens]

var message = {
      notification :{
             title: 'title',
             body: 'this is a test message',
             icon: 'icon-path',
             sound: 'default'
      }
}
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(device_token, message)
.then((response) => {
      console.log('Successfully sent message: ', response);
})
.catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error sending message:', error);
});

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any way to do that with the notification itself, but you could create a custom event and trigger this event when the notification is received. You can add the ad_id or any other unique id to identify which user have received the push and which not.